# Object value can't be read in my todoList

Tags: javascript

I made a TODO list where you can type in something you have to do. When you click on save, the system will add it as a todo-item. When I click on the V the todo item will change to a done item but it can't read the value of it.

How can I fix this? What did I wrong so the code doesn't read the input value?

[image]

```js
const $textArea = document.getElementById("todo-input");
const $saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
const $todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list");
const $todoCount = document.getElementById("todo-count");
const $doneList = document.getElementById("done-list");
const $doneCount = document.getElementById("done-count");
const $clearAllBtn = document.getElementById("clear-all-btn");
const state = {
  focusIndex: NaN,
  todoList: [],
  doneList: [],
};

function setState() {
  fetch("https://phpstack-224488-1624928.cloudwaysapps.com/_/items/todo?filter%5Bdone%5D%5Beq%5D=0", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "bearer ABcEHA2kcrKY4a6ipUA3",
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("could not fetch todoItems");
    }
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(body) {
    state.todoList = body.data;
    printTodoList();
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

function printTodoList() {
  $todoList.innerHTML = "";
  let template = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <
    state.todoList.length; i++) {
    template += ` <div class="box ${
          i === state.focusIndex ? " active " : " "
        }" data-index="${i}">
  <p>${state.todoList[i].description}</p>
  <a class="done-btn fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></a>
  </div>`;
  }
  $todoList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);
  $todoCount.innerText = state.todoList.length;
}

function printDoneList() {
  $doneList.innerHTML = "";
  let template = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <
    state.doneList.length; i++) {
    template += ` <div class="box">
    <p>${state.doneList[i]}</p>
    <a class="remove-btn fas fa-times-circle fa-2x" data-index="${i}"></a>
    </div>`;
  }
  $doneList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);
  $doneCount.innerText = state.doneList.length;
  console.log($doneList);
}

function saveBtnClicked() {
  const body = {
    description: $textArea.value,
    done: false,
  };
  fetch("https://phpstack-224488-1624928.cloudwaysapps.com/_/items/todo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "bearer ABcEHA2kcrKY4a6ipUA3",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  }).then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("could not save todoItem");
    }
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(body) {
    state.todoList.push(body.data);
    printTodoList();
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

function todoListClicked(event) {
  const $target = event.target;
  if ($target.matches(".done-btn")) {
    const curIndex = $target.closest(".box").dataset.index;
    const doneItem = state.todoList.splice(curIndex, 1);
    state.doneList.push(doneItem[0]); // state.doneList = state.doneList.concat(doneItem); // alternatief printTodoList(); printDoneList(); } if ($target.matches(".box") || $target.matches(".box p"))
    {
      const curIndex = parseInt($target.closest(".box").dataset.index);
      state.focusIndex = curIndex === state.focusIndex ? NaN : curIndex;
      printTodoList();
    }
  }

  function doneListClicked(event) {
    const $target = event.target;
    if ($target.matches(".remove-btn")) {
      const curIndex = $target.dataset.index;
      state.doneList.splice(curIndex, 1);
      printDoneList();
    }
  }

  function clearAllBtnClicked() {
    state.todoList = [];
    state.doneList = [];
    printTodoList();
    printDoneList();
  }
  $saveBtn.addEventListener("click", saveBtnClicked);
  $todoList.addEventListener("click", todoListClicked);
  $doneList.addEventListener("click", doneListClicked);
  $clearAllBtn.addEventListener("click", clearAllBtnClicked);
  printDoneList();
  setState();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>TODO or not TODO</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="hero is-primary">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">TODO or not TODO</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="section">
      <div id="input-container">
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control">
            <textarea id="todo-input" class="textarea is-success" placeholder="What to do?"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control is-expanded">
            <button id="save-btn" class="button is-success is-fullwidth">
                                    Save
                                </button>
          </p>
          <p class="control">
            <button id="clear-all-btn" class="button is-danger">
                                    Clear All
                                </button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="count-container">
      Todo: <span id="todo-count">5</span>
    </section>
    <section id="todo-list" class="section no-top-padding">
      <div class="box active">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ad aliquam debitis dolores eos excepturi iusto libero, magnam nulla pariatur provident quibusdam quod, repellendus. A illum laudantium quas reprehenderit voluptas?
        </p>
        <a class="done-btn fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ad aliquam debitis dolores eos excepturi iusto libero, magnam nulla pariatur provident quibusdam quod, repellendus. A illum laudantium quas reprehenderit voluptas?
        </p>
        <a class="done-btn fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ad aliquam debitis dolores eos excepturi iusto libero, magnam nulla pariatur provident quibusdam quod, repellendus. A illum laudantium quas reprehenderit voluptas?
        </p>
        <a class="done-btn fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="count-container">
      Done: <span id="done-count">5</span>
    </section>
    <section id="done-list" class="section no-top-padding">
      <div class="box">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ad aliquam debitis dolores eos excepturi iusto libero, magnam nulla pariatur provident quibusdam quod, repellendus. A illum laudantium quas reprehenderit voluptas?
        </p>
        <a class="remove-btn fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is jquery try *val()* instad of value, here *description: $textArea.value*

Comment: @Aalexander it doesn't work...